# fps setup... camera looks into character... how to fix this?

Tags: game-engine, camera

How can I make the body of my character in the blender game engine invisible (just for the camera) so that I am not able to look inside the body anymore.
I could make a camera collision but thats not so useful for that case because I still want to move my camera fully downwards.

Comment: Why you show the character at all? Is there any situation it will be visible to the camera? If you really need you can have parts of the body like arms and legs. In general it is a good idea to restrict the camera orientation to stay inside a plausible range.

Comment: the reason is the multiplayer otherwise just arms fly around

Comment: You have a splitscreen game (= two players playing at the same window)?

Comment: no, i will make it online but i want to add the multiplayer function later

Comment: In this case your camera will never show the players character. All you see is the character of the other player (which gets remote controlled by the other client). The answer is: You do not need the player character as mesh.